# SQL Insert into query where part of the Select is a substring

Tags: sql, select, insert

Morning All,

I'm trying to create an Insert Into Select query where part of the criteria is obtained from truncating the values in a column eg

```
INSERT INTO tbRoom ([Ref],[Type])

SELECT ([Ref],substring([Description], 1, charIndex(':',[Description] )-1)) FROM tbRoomUsage

WHERE tbRoomUsage.Ref = 1
```

How do I structure the query to do the substring query as part of the overall Insert Into query?

The

```
SELECT substring([Description], 1, charIndex(':',[Description] )-1) FROM tbRoomUsage
```

works fine on its own in terms of selecting the truncated information I need.

Thanks

MG

Comment: Have you considered matching brackets properly? I see at least two `(` in that query that don't have corresponding `)`. *Wait!* Does `Description` contain some SQL that you want to execute as part of that query?

Comment: so what is the problem ?

Comment: Please add a tag for the SQL dialect you're using.

Comment: Hi Anthony. Brackets is an error sorry and 'Description' is a column name only.

Comment: @MG SQL Muppet: The `brackets` on your first line of code are causing the issue. Barmar: Since he is using square brackets to define the columns, I recon it is MS SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the additional and unnecessary brackets and you should be fine

```
INSERT INTO tbRoom ([Ref],[Type])
    SELECT [Ref], substring([Description], 1, charIndex(':',[Description] )-1) 
    FROM tbRoomUsage
    WHERE tbRoomUsage.Ref = 1
```